# Adding user to Twilio channel.

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Is there a way of adding a user to a Twilio channel using the REST API?

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Initialize the client
account = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
token = "your_auth_token"
client = Client(account, token)

# Update the channel
user = client.chat \
                .services("ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").users.list()[0]
channel = client.chat \
                .services("ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") \
                .channels("CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").list()[0]
# How to add user to channel?
```

Answer (score 8):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can [add a member to a channel by creating a member resource using your user's identity](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/members?code-sample=code-add-a-member&code-language=py&code-sdk-version=6.x). So following on from your code you would need:

```
channel.members.create(user.identity)
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Where do you get `user` or what if you want to add an other person?

Comment: This is just an example, all you need is the user's identity.

Comment: I mean the Client SDK has no list user method but the REST API does. Should the 1st person chat client be using the REST API as well or should it get the identity from your backend? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53510298/6656422

Comment: Can we add multiple members in a single call?

Comment: @LJP No, you can't.

Comment: Thank you @philnash