# twilio REST API: strictly backend?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

The [JavaScript chat client SDK](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.0.2/docs/) is missing some functionality that the REST API has, like list users. Should the 1st person chat client be using the REST API as well to supplement gaps in the client SDK or just in general? Or is it strictly for backend management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here

The Chat SDK itself doesn't give all of the same access as the REST API because that would put that access directly in the hands of all users of the Chat SDK. Restricting things like listing users of the app to the REST API means that your application has greater control over those functions and can restrict access or use it only in specific circumstances.

As we've discussed in your other question, how you actually manage things in your application, whether it is by calling to the REST API or storing data in your own user database, is up to you and depends on what will work best for your application.